# Find users in groups, remove duplicates, loop to check if suspended, create new array with results-Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to search for all users in certain groups and just get their email address. Then take those users, combine them and remove duplicates as same user can be in both groups. Lastly I need to check if the user is suspended and create a new array with only users not suspended(false).

Eventually this list of users will be used to make API calls for another application and then write to Google sheets, but for now I'm just trying to get the final list of users.

What I have so far works but seems redundant. Is there a better way to do this? Also not positive how to create the final array after the loop?

```
function getSpecificUser(user) {
  const userDetails = AdminDirectory.Members.list(user);
  return userDetails
}

function userSorting() {
  let groupList = getSpecificUser('group1@xxx.com').members;
  let groupList2 = getSpecificUser('group2@xxx.com').members;
  let groupList3 = getSpecificUser('group3@xxx.com').members;
  let merged = [...groupList,...groupList2,...groupList3]//tried ...new Set in front but not iterable error  
  let mergedMap = merged.map(i => i.email);
  let noDups = [...new Set(mergedMap)];

  for (i in noDups) {
    if (AdminDirectory.Users.get(noDups[i]).suspended === false){
      Logger.log(noDups[i])//need to put final array here?
      
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: don't use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in) on arrays use `for...of`, and it looks like you just want to `filter()` by `suspended`?

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the tip, I read up on why not to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to index unique members by `member.email` and remove the repetitive `getSpecificUser` calls by using a loop over an array of  the group emails.

The final result can then be obtained by filtering the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) by each user's `suspended` property, to either isolate the suspended or active members.

```
function getSpecificUser(user) {
  const userDetails = AdminDirectory.Members.list(user);
  return userDetails
}

function userSorting() {
  const userEmails = ['group1@xxx.com', 'group2@xxx.com', 'group3@xxx.com'];

  const uniqueMembers = new Map();
  for (const email of userEmails) {
    const { members } = getSpecificUser(email);
    for (const member of members) {
      uniqueMembers.set(member.email, member)
    }
  }

  const activeMembers = [...uniqueMembers.values()]
    .filter(({ email }) => !AdminDirectory.Users.get(email).suspended);

  const suspendedMembers = [...uniqueMembers.values()]
    .filter(({ email }) => AdminDirectory.Users.get(email).suspended);
}
```

**Note:** Don't use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in) on arrays, rather use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for iterating array elements directly or `for (const i of [].keys()){...}` ([Array#keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys)) for iterating the indexes of the array.

Comment: How would I return or log this so I get just a list of email address? If I log `activeMembers` I get the entire member object.

Comment: You would just log `activeMembers.map(({email}) => email)`

Answer (score 1):

This would iterate only once over the list of emails. Or twice, considering `Array.from()`.

```js
function getActiveEmails(...mailingGroups) {
  const uniqueEmails = new Set();

  for (let i = 0, len = mailingGroups.length; i < len; i++) {
    const members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(mailingGroups[i])?.members || [];

    for (let j = 0, lenJ = members.length; j < lenJ; j++) {
      const member = members[j];
  
      if (!AdminDirectory.Users.get(member.email)?.suspended) {
        uniqueEmails.add(member.email);
      }
    }
  }

  return Array.from(uniqueEmails);
}

const activeEmails = getActiveEmails("group1@xxx.com", "group2@xxx.com", "group3@xxx.com");

console.log(activeEmails);
```

---

Note that a user can participate in groups using different aliases. If you want to make sure that a **user** (not **email**) is only present once in the list, or if that other API call you mention requires the primary email of the user, you could use something like the following to resolve aliases:

```js
function getActiveEmails(...mailingGroups) {
  const uniqueEmails = new Set();

  for (let i = 0, len = mailingGroups.length; i < len; i++) {
    const members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(mailingGroups[i])?.members || [];

    for (let j = 0, lenJ = members.length; j < lenJ; j++) {
      const member = members[j];
      const user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(member.email);

      if (!user) continue;
  
      if (!user.suspended) {
        // always use the user's primary email
        uniqueEmails.add(user.primaryEmail);
      }
    }
  }

  return Array.from(uniqueEmails);
}

const activeEmails = getActiveEmails("group1@xxx.com", "group2@xxx.com", "group3@xxx.com");

console.log(activeEmails);
```

Comment: Question,, Im not familiar with this `(mailingGroups[i])?.members || [];` From what I understand is that checking there is an object exists in mailGroups OR is not empty?

Comment: It is checking that the **return value** of the call to `.list(maliningGroups[i])` is neither `undefined` nor `null` (see [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)). If the return value is neither of them, get its `.members` property. If the outcome of all this is still falsy, return an empty array `[]`.

Comment: I read up on that link, would that if be the same as `try { for (let i = 0, len = mailingGroups.length; i < len; i++) {
    const members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(mailingGroups[i]).members }} catch(e) { //do something with error}`

Comment: Isolating this very specific scenario, you could say that the **outcome** would be the same. But your suggestion is **not** doing the same thing.  Your try..catch would be catching errors happening anywhere in that expression (or in the entire for loop for that matter), while the optional chaining operator applies to one very specific scenario.